# how to get b tag text from inner tags using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I'm new to jQuery logics and I want to get `b` tag text from inner tags so below is my `html` logic

```
<div class=strikeinfocontent>

<p>
<span>OI : </span>
<b>268400</b>
</p>

<p><span>OI Chg : </span>
<b>51150</b>
</p>

</div>
```

In the above code I should get `b` tags text only

ex: 268400 , 51150

For this I tried below logic but I didn't get any value

jQuery logic

```
var d = i.find(".strikeinfocontent").closest("p >span >b").html();

var t = i.find(".strikeinfocontent").closest("p >span >b").next("p >span >b").html();
```

Please suggest me how to get the `b` tag text?

Comment: problem is that `.closest()` will look for any ancestor of `strikeinfocontent` not children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select all b tags with this selector **".strikeinfocontent p b"** then loop through them using **each** function

```js
$( ".strikeinfocontent p b" ).each(function(index) {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<div class=strikeinfocontent>
  <p>
    <span>OI : </span>
    <b>268400</b>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>OI Chg : </span>
    <b>51150</b>
  </p>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

you can push the texts into an array if you want to save each value in a variable you can do this

```js
let arr = []; 

$( ".strikeinfocontent p b" ).each(function(index) { 
  arr.push($(this).text());
}); 

console.log(arr);

let var_1 = arr[0];
let var_2 = arr[1]; // etc..

console.log(var_1, var_2);
```

```html
<div class=strikeinfocontent>
  <p>
    <span>OI : </span>
    <b>268400</b>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>OI Chg : </span>
    <b>51150</b>
  </p>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```